# latex table problem long-table two Column

Tags: tables, longtable

Integrate a long table to a two research paper latex column paper [image]

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{longtable}
% Note: It may be necessary to compile the document several times to get a multi-page table to line up properly
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Themes         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Data Upload \\ to Cloud\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Emergency Stop\\  Mechanism\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Mapping and Recording \\ Restrictions\end{tabular} & Safety Regulations & Privacy Concerns & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Contact Information\\  Requirement\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\endhead
%
Scenario One   & 4                                                               & 3                                                                   & 4                                                                             & 4                  & 0                & 0                                                                          \\ \hline
Scenario Two   & 7                                                               & 1                                                                   & 2                                                                             & 1                  & 6                & 2                                                                          \\ \hline
Scenario Three & 2                                                               & 5                                                                   & 3                                                                             & 1                  & 3                & 8                                                                          \\ \hline
\caption{TABLE II: Comprehensive Overview: Number of Participants Making Statements Aligned with Key Themes}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: you can use `\onecolumn` before the table and `\twocolumn` after, if the journal publisher allows.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document (with dummy text) which reproduce your problem.  As noted @DavidCarlisle in hs comment, `longtable` doesn't work in twocolumn document. Should table span two columns?